# How i can add an attribute to row and get the settings to the frontend WP Bakery?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

How i can add an attribute to row and get the settings to the frontend WP Bakery ?

I set a value, save it, save page, view it, but there is no affect to frontend. A row still has no attribute.

[image]

```
    // Add Params
$vc_column_text_new_params = array(
     
    // Example
    array(
        'type' => 'textfield',
        'holder' => 'h3',
        'class' => 'class-name',
        'heading' => __( 'Animations', 'text-domain' ),
        'param_name' => 'example',
        'value' => __( 'Default value', 'text-domain' ),
        'description' => __( 'AOS, animate on scroll, css3 scroll animations, simple scroll animations', 'text-domain' ),
        'admin_label' => true,
        'dependency' => '',
        'weight' => 0,
        'group' => 'Animate On Scroll',
    ),      
 
);
 
vc_add_params( 'vc_row', $vc_column_text_new_params );
```

}

Comment: guessing you would need to overwrite `vc_row.php` so that it extracts your parameter, and actually uses it.

Comment: complete guide is here : http://www.wpelixir.com/how-to-customize-default-elements-visual-composer/

Comment: @Stender I visited this link
But I did not understand very well the part talking about: show value to the frontend

Answer (score 1):

You named your new attribute "example".

1. Copy the vc_row.php into the vc_templates directory and include the directory
   in the functions.php
2. Check if your example variable exists and if so, add the value to the data-aos-attribute

```html
 <?php if($example) echo ' data-aos="'.esc_attr($example).'" '; ?>
```

Check if the attribute "example" exisits and if so, add it to as a data-aos-attribute to the div:

```html
<div <?php echo implode( ' ', $wrapper_attributes ); ?>
    <?php echo $style; ?>
    <?php if($data_offset) echo ' data-offset=" '.esc_attr($data_offset).' " '; ?>
    <?php if($example) echo ' data-aos="'.esc_attr($example).'" '; ?>
    <?php echo esc_attr($row_data); ?>>
    <?php echo ''.$html_overlay_row; ?>
    <?php echo ''.$video_style; ?>

    <?php if(!$full_width): ?><div class="container"><div class="row"><?php endif ; ?>
    <?php if($full_width): ?><div class="no-container"><div class="row"><?php endif ; ?>
    <?php echo wpb_js_remove_wpautop( $content ); ?>
    <?php if(!$full_width): ?></div></div><?php endif ; ?>
    <?php if($full_width): ?></div></div><?php endif ; ?>
    <?php echo ''.$link_style; ?>

    <?php echo ''.$html_row_arrow; ?>
</div>
```